# Converting json code to normal html in java

Tags: java, json

I need to convert json code to html. This is an example source:

> \u003Cb\u003EJava\u003C/b\u003E
>   (\u003Cb\u003Eprogramming\u003C/b\u003E language) - Wikipedia, the
>   free encyclopedia\u003C/a\u003E\u003C\

Unfortunately, I can`t convert data from file using 2 below methods. The program result is

> #########FIRST METHOD#############################
>
> \u003Cb\u003EJava\u003C/b\u003E
>   (\u003Cb\u003Eprogramming\u003C/b\u003E language) - Wikipedia, the
>   free encyclopedia\u003C/a\u003E\u003C\
>
> #########SECOND METHOD#############################
>
> \u003Cb\u003EJava\u003C/b\u003E
>   (\u003Cb\u003Eprogramming\u003C/b\u003E language) - Wikipedia, the
>   free encyclopedia\u003C/a\u003E\u003C\

I`m going to convert this data to

> Java<> (programming<> language) - Wikipedia, the free
>   encyclopedia...

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import java.io.*;
public class ParserJSOIUP {
    public static String read(String fileName){
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        try{
            BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), "UTF8"));
            try{
                String s;
                while((s=in.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(s);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
            }finally {
                in.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //###############FIRST METHOD#############################
        Document doc=Jsoup.parse(read("E://Java//eclipse//html.txt"));
        System.out.println(doc.html().toString());
        //###############SECOND METHOD############################
        try{    
            String string=read("E://Java//eclipse//html.txt");
            byte[] converttoBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
            string = new String(converttoBytes, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(string);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help. I am a newby in java and I didn`t find the answer in others topic.

Comment: Where is the JSON data? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

That example souce is not json.

JSON, (canonically pronounced /ˈdʒeɪsən/ jay-sən;[1] sometimes JavaScript Object Notation), is an open standard format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects consisting of attribute–value pairs.

For more details see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

And this is what json looks like

```
{
  "type": "home",
  "number": "212 555-1234"
}
```

Plus once "decoded" that thing looks like this

> \< b>Java\< /b> (\< b>programming\< /b> language) - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia\< /a>\<\

this doesn't have anything to do with json